# How to get GAMS's solvers to work from Pyomo?

Tags: python, optimization, gams-math

I want to run a model written in pyomo language with cplex solver of gams.
however I get the following error:

```
"No 'gams' command found on system PATH - GAMS shell"
NameError: No 'gams' command found on system PATH - GAMS shell solver 
functionality is not available. "
```

I have added the folder (C:\GAMS\win64\25.1) to enviornmental variables of system. 
Pyomo version is 5.6.5. Python is 3.5.2. and GAMS is 25.1.2

I would be grateful if you could provide me with help.

```py
solvername = 'gams'
opt = SolverFactory(solvername)
results = opt.solve(
    instance, solver='cplex', keepfiles=True, tee=True)
```

Comment: I do not have the answer, but I have a feeling if you took this over to the [Operations Research stack exchange site](https://or.stackexchange.com/), someone there would have experience with this.

Comment: Actually, looking at [this pyomo source](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/161c0def11d26af115b26ef812d3b4e1dc72812d/pyomo/solvers/tests/checks/test_GAMS.py#L301), it seems like you could try `opt = SolverFactory("gams", solver_io="cplex")`, possibly also dropping `solver='cplex'` from the options to `opt.solve`.

Comment: @brentertainer thank you. solver_io did not solve the problem. Error: unavailable solver.